# inheritance with no additional elments in XSD

Tags: .net, wcf, web-services, xsd

can someone please tell me whitch of these xsd parts (xsd1 or xsd2) is valid for sample code below:

```
Class definitions:
class A
{
 int prop1;
 int prop2;
}

class B : A {}
```

So, class A is base class and class B inherit A and have no aditional properties.

xsd1: In this case if I use wsimport to generate code from wsdl file that contains this part of xsd I will get generated code for all elements, A and B.
But, if I use svcutil I will get generated only class A.

```
<xs:element name="B" nillable="true" type="tns:A" />
<xs:complexType name="A">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="prop1" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:element name="prop2" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:element name="A" nillable="true" type="tns:A" />
```

xsd1: In this case both wsimport and svcutil will generate all elements, A and B.

```
<xs:complexType name="B">
    <xs:complexContent mixed="false">
        <xs:extension base="tns:A">
            <xs:sequence />
        </xs:extension>
    </xs:complexContent>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:element name="B" nillable="true" type="tns:A" />
<xs:complexType name="A">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="prop1" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:element name="prop2" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
<xs:element name="A" nillable="true" type="tns:A" />
```

So, my question is ... is this first definition valid?

Answer (score 1):

I guess the correct solution is the second.
To explain why maybe is better if you think at complexTypes as classes and at elements as instances.

In your first xsd you are in fact declaring two instances (A and B) of the class A.
In the second you are declaring still two instances of the same class but you also include the definition for the B class.

In fact, I suppose it would be more correct with

```
<xs:element name="B" nillable="true" type="tns:B" />
```

than

```
<xs:element name="B" nillable="true" type="tns:A" />
```